# Terraform with API-Gateway, Route53, and SSL Certification interdependency problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, terraform, amazon-route53, terraform-provider-aws

I can't seem to get an SSL certificate from ACM working on API-Gateway, Route53, using terraform. There seems to be an interdependency problem.

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "root_domain" {
  name         = "${var.route53_root_domain_name}"
  private_zone = false
}

# The domain name to use with api-gateway
resource "aws_api_gateway_domain_name" "domain_name" {
  domain_name = "${var.route53_sub_domain_name}"

  certificate_arn = "${aws_acm_certificate.cert.arn}"
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "sub_domain" {
  name    = "${var.route53_sub_domain_name}"
  type    = "A"
  zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.root_domain.zone_id}"

  alias {
    name                   = "${aws_api_gateway_domain_name.domain_name.cloudfront_domain_name}"
    zone_id                = "${aws_api_gateway_domain_name.domain_name.cloudfront_zone_id}"
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate" "cert" {
  # api-gateway / cloudfront certificates need to use the us-east-1 region
  provider          = "aws.cloudfront-acm-certs"
  domain_name       = "${var.route53_sub_domain_name}"
  validation_method = "DNS"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "cert_validation" {
  name    = "${aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_name}"
  type    = "${aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_type}"
  zone_id = "${aws_route53_record.sub_domain.zone_id}"
  records = ["${aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_value}"]
  ttl     = 60
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "cert" {
  # api-gateway / cloudfront certificates need to use the us-east-1 region
  provider          = "aws.cloudfront-acm-certs"

  certificate_arn         = "${aws_acm_certificate.cert.arn}"
  validation_record_fqdns = ["${aws_route53_record.cert_validation.fqdn}"]
}
```

The problem appears to be that:

1. aws_api_gateway_domain_name requires aws_acm_certificate
2. aws_acm_certificate has to be validated, so step 3
3. aws_route53_record.cert_validation requires aws_route53_record.sub_domain
4. aws_route53_record.subdomain requires aws_api_gateway_domain_name
5. Go to 1

Everytime I try to use the configuration given, I get the following error:

> aws_api_gateway_domain_name.domain_name: Error creating API Gateway
>   Domain Name: BadRequestException: Unable to associate certificate
>   arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:yyyy:certificate/zzzz with CloudFront. This
>   error may prevent the domain name audit-log.taspli.com from being used
>   in API Gateway for up to 40 minutes. Please ensure the certificate
>   domain name matches the requested domain name, and that this user has
>   permission to call cloudfront:UpdateDistribution on '*' resources.
>     status code: 400, request id: xxxx

Comment: `3. aws_route53_record.cert_validation requires aws_route53_record.sub_domain` is false.  It only requires the validation records, not the record for the subdomain that is the subject of the certificate.  You can prove this for yourself by manually creating an DNS-validated ACM cert for a nonexistent subdomain in a working Route 53 hosted zone.  The error message suggests only that the cert has not *yet* been validated, not that validation can't/won't succeed.

Comment: ah, so I can remove the zone_id field and then it'll succeed anyway? How would it know where to add the record as it's parent if not the domain I'm creating it on?

Comment: ok, so I validated my claim that the aws_route53_record for cert validation requires the zone_id. Therefore the zone the records are being attached to have to exist first before it can attach the records. This makes sense. The problem then is that the aws_route53_record for the sub domain where it's being attached needs the records from the api gateway domain name in order to attach the alias to the cloudfront distribution that api gateway creates. So again, it's just another cyclic dependency that I'm unsure how to resolve.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I seem to have fixed the problem by adding the certificate validation records to the root domain instead of the sub domain. Therefore breaking the cyclic dependency.

The problem appears to be that the sub domain can't be created without the certificate and the certificate can't be validated without the sub domain. So the situation is stuck and unresolvable.

You could manually create the sub domain, but then whats the point in automation if you have to make manual efforts to solve problems.

So I tried adding the cert validation records to the root. Suddenly it starts to work, because the root domain is something that is created externally to the project. A sort of global infrastructure project which can be handled externally. Then your individual projects can hang off of that infrastructure on a case-by-case basis.

Here is the terraform configuration which worked:

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "root_domain" {
  name         = "${var.route53_root_domain_name}"
  private_zone = false
}

# The domain name to use with api-gateway
resource "aws_api_gateway_domain_name" "domain_name" {
  domain_name = "${var.route53_sub_domain_name}"

  certificate_arn = "${aws_acm_certificate.cert.arn}"
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "sub_domain" {
  name    = "${var.route53_sub_domain_name}"
  type    = "A"
  zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.root_domain.zone_id}"

  alias {
    name                   = "${aws_api_gateway_domain_name.domain_name.cloudfront_domain_name}"
    zone_id                = "${aws_api_gateway_domain_name.domain_name.cloudfront_zone_id}"
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate" "cert" {
  # api-gateway / cloudfront certificates need to use the us-east-1 region
  provider          = "aws.cloudfront-acm-certs"
  domain_name       = "${var.route53_sub_domain_name}"
  validation_method = "DNS"
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "cert_validation" {
  name    = "${aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_name}"
  type    = "${aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_type}"
  zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.root_domain.zone_id}"
  records = ["${aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_value}"]
  ttl     = 60
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "cert" {
  # api-gateway / cloudfront certificates need to use the us-east-1 region
  provider          = "aws.cloudfront-acm-certs"

  certificate_arn         = "${aws_acm_certificate.cert.arn}"
  validation_record_fqdns = ["${aws_route53_record.cert_validation.fqdn}"]

  timeouts {
    create = "45m"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Christopher Thomas thank you for your initial answer

With current terraform version it needs some modifications in the certificate blocks and I propose to set a provider in case your main region is not us-east-1. Since the changes are too long for a comment I add another answer for now

```
# api-gateway / cloudfront certificates need to use the us-east-1 region
provider "aws" {
  alias = "virginia"
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate" "cert" {
  provider = aws.virginia
  domain_name       = local.api_subdomain
  validation_method = "DNS"
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "cert" {
  provider = aws.virginia
  certificate_arn         = "${aws_acm_certificate.cert.arn}"
  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.cert_validation : record.fqdn]
}


resource "aws_route53_record" "cert_validation" {

  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name   = dvo.resource_record_name
      record = dvo.resource_record_value
      type   = dvo.resource_record_type
    }
  }


  name            = each.value.name
  records         = [each.value.record]
  type            = each.value.type

  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.root_domain.zone_id
  ttl     = 60
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "cert" {
  provider = aws.virginia
  certificate_arn         = "${aws_acm_certificate.cert.arn}"
  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.cert_validation : record.fqdn]
}

# Finally Hook up Custom api domain name with api stage
resource "aws_api_gateway_base_path_mapping" "avxapi_base_path_mapping" {
  api_id      = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.xxxxxx.id
  stage_name  = aws_api_gateway_stage.xxxx.stage_name
  domain_name = aws_api_gateway_domain_name.xxxx.domain_name
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I actually did set the provider like this, but I didn't put that into my answer. So I think this is good to know for people coming here and wondering how I was doing that. Thanks again!

Comment: I also added some adaptions to the cert_validation instead of using 0 index which somehow does not work anymore I went with with an terraform example with for_each and for

Answer (score 0):

For me I have changed the `aws_route53_record.cert_validation` resource and it worked:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "cert_validation" {
  name    = "${tolist(aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options)[0].resource_record_name}"
  type    = "${tolist(aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options)[0].resource_record_type}"
  zone_id = "${aws_route53_record.sub_domain.zone_id}"
  records = ["${tolist(aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options)[0].resource_record_value}"]
  ttl     = 60
}
```

Comment: apart from using tolist(), this seems to be the same code? what am I missing?